# this function parameter: access private members

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a custom Log method decorator.
This decorator replaces the method with a custom method which accesses a private class member:

```
export function Log(level: LogLevel) {

return function(target: MyClass, _propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
   const original = decorator.value;

   decorator.value = function(this:MyClass ) {
      this.privateMember.doStuff();
    }
 };
}
```

But this results in an error beacuse the member is private. On the other hand the new method is invoked in the context of a member of the class and should have access to the private members.
So is there a type like This< MyClass > or anything to allow to access the priavte members?

Comment: pls share reproducable example in ts playground

Comment: Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEQKYTgJwIZSwCim0wHNUoAuRAWQE8BhAG2wGcWAaRAfQAdM4eqTFFoBpVLSosomGGBKcAJqhYRZPPJioAFfoOG00q9ZoCUiAN4AoRLcQYw0xFhgk52RogC8iZcZgaWAB0AG4eIKgA3FY2dn5qAZqh4ajeiKCQsAiEABYwLFR0TKws5tZ2FYhQeSxBALa0AGrEaQDkyhg4mvYejKiKrZGIAPTDiEL8mLG2AL4xc1YQzGw0DMssltOIfDBhUKkNzVqI0rLybYMxFTwgAEaMMBC+cADKUCDAwPhlWxWjKAB5E7vT5bOYzIA

Comment: How do you apply this decorator?

Comment: You can use getter for this

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEQKYTgJwIZSwCim0wHNUoAuRAWQE8BhAG2wGcWAaRAfQAdM4eqTFFoBpVLSosomGGBKcAJqhYRZPPJioAFfoOG00q9ZoCUiAN4AoRLcQYw0xFhgk52RogC8iZcZgaWAB0AG4eIKgA3FY2dn5qAZqh4ajeiKCQsAiEABYwLFR0TKws5tZ2FYhQeSxBALa0AGrEaQDkyhg4mvYejKiKrZGIAPTDiEL8mLG2AL4xc1YQzGw0DMssltOIfDBhUKkNzVqI0rLybYMxFQACaJ24WFs8IABGjDAQvnAAylAgwMB8GUthVRigAPInP4ArZzGZAA

Comment: A Getter is not the option i would like, because the member shoud stay private. The  function injected by the decorator should have access, because it replaces a member function.